# Can't locate pdf file in express server, sent from angular file uploader (npm library)

Tags: javascript, angular, express, http

I have this in my html:

```
<angular-file-uploader
        [(ngModel)]="pdfUrl"
        (ngModelChange)="onChangeCN('pdf')"
        [config]="afuConfig"
        (ApiResponse)="pdfUpload($event)"
        name="file-uploader"
        ngDefaultControl
        class="ion-padding-top ion-float-left"
      ></angular-file-uploader>
```

This is my `afuConfig` in my component:

```
   afuConfig = {
      formatsAllowed: '.pdf',
      uploadAPI: {
        url: `${SERVER_URL}`,
        method: 'POST',
        responseType: 'blob',
        params: {
          token: this.loginService.token,
        },
      },
    }
```

Attaching a file triggers an http post request to my express server (`SERVER_URL`) and I can see the the token from the params in `req.query.token` (although thinking about it, I am not sure if this a secure way of getting the token).

What I can't seem to see anywhere when I debug the call as it hits the express server is the actual file!!

I have been looking at this for a while now and I just can't see it.

Does anyone know what property to look for or maybe what format the file comes across in so I can track it down?

Comment: l noticed that `req.body` is empty, l think that is where the file should be.

Answer (score 0):

It was because the angular file uploader library sends the data as a multipart form and needs to be handled accordingly on the server (I used the npm library multer).